# Is regular water incursion into the ear considered beneficial or harmful?

Tags: health-outcomes, ears-nose-throat-ent, earwax, ear-irrigation

I've never been terribly comfortable getting water in my ear.  Others swear part of a proper bathing is rinsing ears out.  I can imagine cleansing could be important, I can also envision that water would alter wax chemistry/effectiveness.

What is the medical/scientific stance on this?  Are there common significant health issues that weigh it one way or the other, or is it generally shown to be of minimal difference... or alternatively considered an unanswered question as of yet?

I see [this](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4947/washing-the-ear) question got no firm responses, but hope that by limiting it to one specific detail, it would be something people can give more clear information about.